In Bereshit 1:14, what does it mean that "they shall be for signs"?
What kind of "signs"?:

Bereshit 1:14 And God said, "Let there be luminaries in the expanse of the heavens, to separate between the day and between the night, and they shall be for signs and for appointed seasons and for days and years.


I remember answering this exact question on this site at some point... The basic meaning is that the sun, moon and stars can and should be used to calculate the times of seasons, festivals etc. (and be for omens etc. see Rashi there)

I sort of expected that but I was unable to locate it. Have you a link?

Sorry can't find it but don't have bags of time to look at the moment
